# Regular expression for substring which shall not be preceded by number

Tags: c#, regex

I use `"[a-z][a-z0-9]*"` to find substrings:

> "as4s" - found as4s
>
> "s+sd4" - found s, sd4
>
> "(4asd sad)" - found asd, sad
>
> "10asd" - found asd

I need to change this exprassion so result would be:

> "as4s" - found as4s
>
> "s+sd4" - found s, sd4
>
> "(4asd sad)" - found sad
>
> "10asd" - found nothing

You can use this code to test expression:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

string input = "A*10+5.01E+10";
Regex r = new Regex("[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\d]*");
var identifiers = new Dictionary<string, string>();

MatchEvaluator me = delegate(Match m)
{
    Console.WriteLine(m);
    var variableName = m.ToString();

    if (identifiers.ContainsKey(variableName))
    {
        return identifiers[variableName];
    }
    else
    {
        i++;
        var newVariableName = "i" + i.ToString();
        identifiers[variableName] = newVariableName;
        return newVariableName;
    }
};

input = r.Replace(input, me);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use **word boundary** to avoid matching unwanted text i.e. preceded by a digit etc:

```
Regex r = new Regex("\b[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\d]*\b");
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lJ0pM4/1)

Comment: Thanks! Now i know what is `\b`.

Answer (score 1):

```
(?<!\d)(\b[a-z][a-z0-9]*)
```

Try this.Grab the capture.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/gX5qF3/7

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<!                     look behind to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d                       digits (0-9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w)
                         and something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [a-z]                    any character of: 'a' to 'z'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [a-z0-9]*                any character of: 'a' to 'z', '0' to '9'
                         (0 or more times (matching the most
                         amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
```

Comment: `(?<!\d)` isn't even needed since you have `\b`